# jQuery tab menu. Switching between tabs

Tags: jquery, menu, tabs

I tried write code for tab menu, however smth. in code is wrong. I tried fix code but without result.

javascript:

```
var tabActive = $(".active").attr('id');
var c=$('a').click(function() {

  $(this).find("div.noactive").removeClass("noactive").addClass("active");
  $(this).find("div"+tabActive).removeClass("active").addClass("noactive");

    var bb = $(this).find("div"+tabActive);
    var b = $(this).attr("class");

      $(".ho").removeClass('ho');
});
```

html:

```
<div id="tabs-wrapper">
  <a  href="#1" class="ho">
     <div id="tab1" class="noactive" >1</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#2" class="">
     <div id="tab2" class="active">2</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#3" class="ho">
     <div id="tab3" class="noactive">3</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#4" class="ho">
     <div id="tab4" class="noactive">4</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#5"class="ho">
     <div id="tab5" class="noactive">5</div>
  </a>

  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div id="tab-content">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy 
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dimaomni/Q2XST/1/

Comment: What does _smth. in code is wrong_ mean? :) .. Include the code in this question and most likely someone will answer ;)

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code to reproduce it** — **in the question itself**.

Comment: So it is the _switching of the tabs_ that does not work? Would be nice to clarify that before people start to post answers ..

Comment: Sorry for poor issue description, however I attached code which is reproduce typical part of interface and as you can find not perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about some good old fashion jQuery chaining....

```
var c = $('a').click(function () {
  $(this).find('div').add('.active')
    .toggleClass("noactive").toggleClass("active")
    .closest('a').toggleClass('ho');
});
```

## [Demo...](http://jsfiddle.net/nWjd4/)

Answer (score 0):

javascript is event-driven, so:

```
$('a').on({
  click: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // stops it from default action
    var showTab = $(this).attr("href"); // gets the href as identifier
    $('.active').removeClass("active"); // removed previous active link
    $(this).addClass("active"); // adds .active to clicked <a>
    $('.tab-content:visible').hide();  // hides visible tab
    $(showTab).show();  // shows active tab
  }
});
```

for html, you shouldn't add a block element to a inline element like  or . It should look like this:

```
<div class="controller">
  <a href="#tab1" class="active">Tab 1</a>
  <a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
  <a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
</div>

<div class="tabs">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab-content">...</div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab-content">...</div>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab-content">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why shouldn't? Is it rule or it  can influence on rest HTML-elements?

Comment: As you can see by your code it isn't a rule. But remember that machine reads differently, it's not as flexible. By adhering to the guidelines, it makes your web more friendly for the browsers and crawlers.